# Mount static binaries into kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory

This is a very common pattern: "add binary such as kubectl, gotemplate into pod container at runtime".

To do this, we can use `initContainer` to download the file from internet, then use an `emptyDir` volume to share it with the main container.

I am wondering if there is a better way / best practice to achieve it? (operator, artifactory, PVC, HTTP proxy ?)

Comment: Isn't "immutable" container images a good practice? instead of "mutating" the content?

Comment: Well, I have worked on 13 big different k8s projects, and see more than 99% containers using ConfigMap as volume to mout files at runtime ^^ I guess this is a good practice on kubernetes ^^

Comment: It sounds very strange if 99% of your containers copy files from internet into the containers. That is certainly not a good security practice. Trends typically go more towards "immutable infrastructure", now also with signed artifacts (e.g. sigstore cosign).

Comment: The system I work on professionally _never_ does this FWIW.  Adding CLI tools like `kubectl` into an application container that doesn't know how to run them doesn't seem that useful (if the application needs to access the Kubernetes API it should use a client library).  Do you have a specific case where it's necessary?

Comment: @Jonas of course I am talking about immutable container,  this is what you said first, not "immutable infrastructure". I said in k8s, everyone use ConfigMap with Pod, so containers are never immutable on k8s. "immutable infrastructure" is exactly what I try to achieve.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am saying all my containers are mutable, because the use of ConfigMap to answer to Jonas about ""immutable" container images". Use cases: "use kubectl with https://github.com/ricoberger/script_exporter Docker image". I am not saying this is a good practice at all but a common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it can be resolved on few different levels.

If this is possible I would start with `container image`.
You can copy the binary in a build process so it will be bake and your image will be immutable.

Example:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/kubectl:1.25.5 AS kubectl

FROM docker.io/jenkins/agent:4.13-3

USER root

COPY --from=kubectl /opt/bitnami/kubectl/bin/kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

RUN usermod --shell /bin/bash jenkins

USER jenkins

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent"]
```

If downloading needed binary is not possible in build process we can also go with `ENTRYPOINT` where we provide some script which will download something to specific location or will install something. With this approach we can use environment variables to parametrize our script. Drawback of that is image is not immutable.

Last option is to use some k8s resources like mentioned `initContainer` or `configMap`.

To summarize I would recommend first approach as the best option from security point of view. If that is not possible you need to choose where to put download step. If you are the owner of application `Dockerfile` and k8s choose what suits you best. If developers are the owner of app and they are producing container image I would go with some k8s resource since it will be easier for you to manage it.

Comment: Thanks you, but I am searching to do this at "runtime".

Answer (score 0):

`...use initContainer to download`

How about maintaining such files on a NFS where your container can mount at runtime. This way you do not need to download every time the pod starts, also provide you a way to pre-screeen, signed and approve files that can be use in the cluster.

Comment: thanks you, yes this is what I am thinking to do, but looking for a clean solution, didnt find yet, so I am doing a cron job to sync an artifactory with a k8s PVC.